# Box colider is not showing away from sktechup object

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, sketchup

i have imported sktechup object inn unity. then i have apply the box coilder on a object but itishowing far away from the object i have try to rescal it and adjust it on a object but its not work. actually i want to movie and transform it in VR. thats why i am using ray caster with a camera. So,the rays will pass through the object because there is no any colider on a object. [image]

Comment: Try change size of BoxCollider :D. May it too small ..

Comment: as i have mentioned above i have try to rescale colider but its not work

Comment: check again center of BoxCollider i see pivot of mesh is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:
Move Center of your box collider and resize it.

Solution 2:
Add empty gameobject to you object as child. Set its(empty gameobject) position to the center of your object. Add box collider to that empty object and resize it.

Comment: or add the box collider into the actual mesh object (not the root transform)